# Why tablesorter row CSS animation resets whenever it resorts

Tags: css, css-animations, tablesorter

I use tablesorter 2 to create a sortable table. As I have some live data will come in from backend server, I want to highlight the changes, so I created a CSS animation like this

```
@keyframes highlightfade {
  from { background: #0081FF; }
  to { background: transparent; }
}

.highlight {
  animation: highlightfade 5s;
}
```

Then, when the data arrive, I add a highlight class to the cell

```
$(this).addClass('highlight');
```

Also trigger the sorting

```
$("table").trigger("updateCell",[this, resort, callback]);
```

The animation and sorting works, except all animation of previous animated cell will be reset. Here's the demo code

https://jsfiddle.net/r4vse9f0/1/

You can click on the "total" column cell to see what's going on here.

[image]

Why resort will make all animation reset for the previous animated cell? Is there a way to avoid that?

Update:

I just found that `jQuery.animate` works fine with tablesorter, not sure why CSS approach doesn't work

Comment: When a column is sorted, the rows are removed from the DOM and added back in the new order; that's why the animation resets.